# Using a list box based on a query

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to pass a value from a list box which is created from a select query.  I am trying to pass the numerical value called 'Hierarchy' to a table which i created called tblHoldingGovernanceCommitteeID.  I would like to take the queried value in my list box and bring it to the field 'ID_GovCommittee' within the table 'tblHoldingGovernanceCommitteeID'.  Unfortunately, the routine executes but no value is passed to the table.  My code is as follows:

```
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblHoldingGovernanceCommitteeID", dbOpenDynaset)
rst.AddNew
rst!ID_GovCommittee = Hierarchy
rst.Update
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help diagnose / understand how the ListBox works, here is some code you can try. Just change the names to match the name of your ListBox control, and select the correct column. Look at the displays sent to the Immediate Window.

```
Private Sub lstHierarchy_AfterUpdate()
Dim strHierarchy    As String
Dim iRows           As Integer
Dim iCols           As Integer
Dim i               As Integer
Dim strPrint        As String

Dim varItem         As Variant

    iRows = Me.lstHierarchy.ListCount       ' # rows (Items) in the listbox
    iCols = Me.lstHierarchy.ColumnCount     ' # columns in the listbox

    Debug.Print "Listbox has "; iRows & " rows; and " & iCols & " columns."

    Debug.Print "Count of Items Selected (if Multi-Select allowed): " & Me.lstHierarchy.ItemsSelected.Count


    For Each varItem In Me.lstHierarchy.ItemsSelected           ' Loop through the items selected (if multi-select allowed)
        strPrint = ""
        For i = 0 To iCols                                      ' Loop thru each column in a row
            strPrint = strPrint & "|" & Me.lstHierarchy.Column(i, varItem)
        Next i
        Debug.Print "Selected Value: " & strPrint               ' Display the row; columns are delimited with '|'
    Next

    strHierarchy = Me.lstHierarchy.Column(0, varItem)       ' Change the Column from 0 to desired column.

    ' This is your code (note I changed the name Hierarchy to strHierarchy)
    Dim rst As DAO.recordSet
    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblHoldingGovernanceCommitteeID", dbOpenDynaset)
    rst.AddNew
    rst!ID_GovCommittee = strHierarchy
    rst.Update
    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much Wayne I will let you know how it works shortly.